# what the float in a printf's expression means

Tags: c

I just came through the following statement:

```
printf("%d days total: %.1f%% were below freezing.\n",all_days, 100.0 * (float) cold_days / all_days);
```

I need an explanation over using `(float)` inside `printf` expression in the above statement. If you have any reference please link it.

Comment: This is a feature called *type casting*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also worth noting that this cast is likely **unneccesary**. `100.0 * (float) cold_days / all_days` will be executed left to right, and since `100.0` is already floating-point number (`double`), result of `100.0 * cold_days` will also be `double`.

And since `float` is upgraded to `double` for printf (as well as any other variadic argument function), the cast is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You cast integer to float with `(float) cold_days`.

Read more about casting at [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This is explicit conversion to float. See this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm